# Modifying data in node.js when its coming in as chuncks

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, post

Ok, so I want to modify data based on what is being received here. All the data that the server receives via the POST method is dealt with in chunks.
This is the HTML code:

```
  <button id='helloButton'>Greet the server with hello!</button>
  <button id='whatsUpButton'>Greet the server with what's up!</button>
   helloButton.onclick = function() {

  xmlHttp.open('POST','/greeting', true);
  xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type','text');
  xmlHttp.send('hello'); 
 }

whatsUpButton.onclick = function() {
xmlHttp.open('POST','/greeting', true);
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type','text');
xmlHttp.send('what\'s up'); 
 }
```

Now in my server.js file I have node.js set up and all I want to do is if the incoming data =="hello", replace with "hello there", if incoming data=="what's up" replace with "the sky" else "good morning".After Ive modified the data I need to append it into the "hi_log.txt" file.

```
  if (request.method === 'POST' && request.url === '/greeting') {
  let body=[]
  request.on("data",chunk=>{
    body.push(chunk);
  });

  request.on("end",chunk=>{
    var newbody='';
    body=Buffer.concat(body).toString()+"\n";
    console.log(body);
    
   if (body.localeCompare("hello")){
      body.replace(body,"hello there \n");
   }
    else if(body.localeCompare("what\'s up")){
      body.replace(body,'the sky \n');
   }
     else{
       body.replace(body,'good morning \n');
     }
  
    fs.appendFileSync("hi_log.txt",body);
    response.end(body);
  });
  
}
```

But it doesn't work and I don't know how to proceed. I am very new at node.Can someone please help me with this and suggest some good documentation where i can understand this?

Comment: Can you tell what specifically is not working?

Comment: It doesn't change the body variable value from "hello" to "hello there" and the "what's up" to "the sky".

Comment: Are you sure the if statement works? `toString()` uses by default utf-8 is that correct?

Comment: That's the problem I am facing. The body doesn't even enter the if statement. I don't know how to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the localeCompare documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)

> Return value  A negative number if referenceStr occurs before compareString; positive if the referenceStr occurs after compareString; 0 if they are equivalent.

So you should use something else like:

```
if (body.includes("hello")) {
   body = "hello there";
} else if(body.includes("what\'s up")) {
   body = 'the sky';
} else {
   body = 'good morning';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
request.on("end", chunk => {
    body = Buffer.concat(body).toString();
    console.log(body);

    if (body === "hello") {
       body = "hello there";
    } else if(body === "what\'s up") {
       body = 'the sky';
    } else {
       body = 'good morning';
    }

    body += ' \n';

    fs.appendFileSync("hi_log.txt",body);
    response.end(body);
});
```

Comment: that just gives out "good morning".Doesn't change anything else.

Comment: As stated by @FayezNazzal, replace the equality check with the ̀include` method call.